# How can I set the ratio of the axis to 1:1 when plotrange->1 or how can I scale a rectangle according to the axis

Tags: plotting

I have a `ListPlot` function

```
lp2 := 
 ListPlot[{#} & /@ #1, 
   PlotMarkers -> {Graphics@{Rectangle[]}, #2}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1, 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> Hue /@ RandomReal[1, {Length@#1}], 
   Epilog -> {GrayLevel[.3], PointSize[.02], Point@#1, Thick, Line@#1}, 
   Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> All
 ] &
```

which attempts to add a unit rectangle centered on each point however this relies on having constant axis to scale the unit rectangle to fit the axis. When `PlotRange->All` the axis ignores the aspect ratio and pretty much everything else. Is it possible to alter this behavior or scale the rectangle to the size of the axis chosen by Mathematica?

Comment: "unit rectangle" - I don't understand; as a rectangle has width and height, there should be two parameters, no? What dimensions were you expecting for these rectangles?

Comment: @J.M. I assume he means a unit square: the default shape of `Rectangle[]`.

Comment: Ooops, yeah, a unit square is defined as Rectangle[] in mathematica sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @user Please review my answer below and tell me if that is what you want.  If it is, I will also suggest a way to do this bypassing `ListPlot` and using Graphics primitives directly.

Comment: Looks like this is related to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011923/how-can-i-plot-a-list-returned-by-the-mathematica-solution-to-in-bounded-integer/9013107#9013107) SO question and my answer there. to change the markers from squares to rectangles with aspect ratio that matches the aspect ratio of the plot, you need to use a second argument to the `Graphics` that define the plot markers: instead of `Graphics@{Rec..}` use `Graphics[{Rectangle[]},AspectRatio->.5` (say).

Comment: @kguler that answer of yours was languishing with zero votes; corrected.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thank you!! Just noticed your second answer below. Glad that i was not way off in my answer to the SO question:) BTW, I was using `SetDelayed` as a substitute for `;` to suppress the output.

Comment: @kguler that is a useful trick but I am concerned by the mixing of purpose.  If the RHS should be evaluated, which can have important effects for both efficiency and result, then this causes problems.  It also obfuscates the purpose and nature of the assignment.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I agree. Yet another TIL,  and a bad habit to be corrected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on your needs is may be both simpler and more flexible to bypass `ListPlot` completely and do this directly in `Graphics`.  Here is a simple example:

```
dat = RandomReal[11, {15, 2}];

Graphics[{
   {Hue @ RandomReal[], Rectangle[# - 0.5]} & /@ #,
   {GrayLevel[.3], PointSize[.02], Point@#, Thick, Line@#}
  },
  AspectRatio -> 0.5,
  Frame -> True
] & @ dat
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 7):

Try your plot followed by:

```
/. Inset -> (Inset[#, #2, Automatic, 1] &)
```

Like:

```
lp2[args] /. Inset -> (Inset[#, #2, Automatic, 1] &)
```

This works by post-processing the `Graphics` object that in generated by ListPlot.  The function `Infix` is used to place the PlotMarkers.  Normally it is using *without* the size argument to keep the plot markers an absolute size.  You want the markers unit size which can be done with:
`Inset[_, _, _, 1]`.

You should get something like this:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can of course include this in your definition of lp2 but I am not sure of your syntax so I did not want to make the change myself.

---

You can specify an explicit aspect ratio for the PlotMarkers *while using this*, e.g. (in the definition of lp2):

```
PlotMarkers -> {Graphics[{Rectangle[]}, AspectRatio -> 0.5]}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you need help rolling this into your function let me know.

---

As a side note you do not need SetDelayed (`:=`) when defining a pure function (`&`); use Set (`=`).

Answer (score 5):

Although I'm a bit late in answering this, I thought it's worth pointing out for completeness that there's actually a built-in function that is basically designed to do **exactly** what this question asks for: [`ErrorListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ErrorBarPlots/ref/ErrorListPlot.html) as shown below where I just modify the given definition slightly in the first few lines:

```
Needs["ErrorBarPlots`"]

lp3 = ErrorListPlot[{#, ErrorBar[{}]} & /@ #1, 
    ErrorBarFunction -> 
     Function[{coords, errs}, {EdgeForm[Orange], LightOrange, 
       Rectangle[coords - #2/2, coords + #2/2]}],
    AspectRatio -> 1, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    PlotStyle -> Hue /@ RandomReal[1, {Length@#1}], 
    Epilog -> {GrayLevel[.3], PointSize[.02], Point@#1, Thick, 
      Line@#1}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All] &;
```

The function allows you to specify the option [`ErrorBarFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ErrorBarPlots/ref/ErrorBarFunction.html), and there is an example in the documentation showing how a rectangle can be constructed based on the errors in the data. Here I adapted that example to use a constant error in both horizontal and vertical directions.

Here is a set of test data - using differently scaled real numbers instead of integers:

```
data = {30, 10} # & /@ RandomReal[1, {15, 2}]

(*
==> {{15.0817, 8.63497}, {29.1274, 4.68834}, {3.86173, 
  2.3385}, {14.3022, 0.452592}, {2.81023, 9.56299}, {27.9932, 
  1.82105}, {1.35937, 0.0468926}, {9.20839, 2.01352}, {2.8601, 
  7.20318}, {11.0419, 1.71997}, {19.9694, 6.43578}, {10.9362, 
  6.84062}, {6.76464, 8.23109}, {21.5031, 4.1016}, {28.083, 6.58259}}
*)

lp3[data, 1]
```

[image: ErrorListPlot]

**Edit**

Since the original question had variable colors, I should also add that to my solution. Here I color the edge according to the distance from the origin, and the inside according to the angle with the $x$ axis:

```
lp4 = ErrorListPlot[{#, ErrorBar[{}]} & /@ #1, 
    ErrorBarFunction -> 
     Function[{coords, errs}, {EdgeForm[Hue[Norm[coords]/20]], 
       Hue[2/Pi ArcTan @@ coords], 
       Rectangle[coords - #2/2, coords + #2/2]}], AspectRatio -> 1, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
    Epilog -> {GrayLevel[.3], PointSize[.02], Point@#1, Thick, 
      Line@#1}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All] &;

lp4[data, 2]
```

[image: colored boxes]