# Coloring Points in a Plot, based on their position in the list

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

Before I describe the question, I'd like to say that I've seen the excellent answers posted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5185/coloring-points-in-a-list-plot) but have not managed to get them to work for my own data.

I have a list of values that I would like to plot in polar coordinates. The values represent the position of a series of coupled pendulums, and as such while the angle changes the radius does not. Here is a sample of the data for the pendulums, at a certain time `t`.

```
position = {
  {-1.25084, 1}, {-1.42995, 1}, {-1.7497, 1}, {-1.83175, 1}, {-1.733,1}, {-1.86803, 1}, 
  {-1.79935, 1}, {-1.87909, 1}, {-1.78354, 1}, {-1.81614, 1}, {-1.58559, 1}, {-1.71751, 1}, 
  {-1.72079, 1}, {-1.60622, 1}, {-1.72122, 1}, {-1.46695, 1}, {-1.62577, 1}, {-1.75079, 1}, 
  {-0.89456, 1}, {-0.950143, 1}, {-1.5654, 1}
}
```

What I would like to do is to color each of the pendulum based on their position; that is, the first pendulum (with angle -1.25084) would be colored purple, the next (with angle -1.42995) slightly purplish-blue and all the way to the last pendulum (with angle -1.5654) being colored red.

The purpose of coloring the pendulums as such is that, as I vary time `t` using `Manipulate`, I would then be able to track the pendulums by their color.

My attempt at this is below, but somehow it doesn't work in the way I intend it to.

```
n = Length[Transpose[position][[1]]]
position = Transpose[{Transpose[position][[1]], (1 + 0.001*Range[n]/n)}];
(* adding a small modifier to the radius of each pendulum to allow me to 
   identify the specific pendulum and give it a color later *)
pendulumcolor = ColorData["Rainbow"][1000*(#2 - 1)] &;
(* defining a colour function that extracts the pendulum number and relates 
   it to a color *)
ListPolarPlot[position, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick, 
  Joined -> True, 
  ColorFunction -> pendulumcolor] /. 
    Line[a__] :> {AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[a]}
```

My output looks something like this, which is definitely not what I intended. The colors of each point should be different, rather than being all red.

[image]

**Edit**:In response to VLC's request, a sample of my code is provided below.

```
n = 100;
(* n is the number of pendulums in our system *)

pendulumplotstyle = 
  Table[Directive[PointSize[Large], ColorData["Rainbow"][Mod[i, 10]/10]], {i, 0, n}];
(* every ten pendula are coloured to span the color of the rainbow *)

Manipulate[
  ListPolarPlot[List /@ funcposition[tdummy], 
    PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    PlotStyle -> pendulumplotstyle],
  {tdummy, 0, 10, 0.001}]
```

In the above code, we have a function `funcposition[t]` that gives the position of the pendulums as a function of time `t`. This function is a numerical solution to an ODE that I'd rather not put up because of the length. The code will not work as-is due to the presence of `funcposition[t]` but it should give a good idea of what I'm doing.

Comment: thank you @Nasser, I defined `n` somewhere else in the kernel and didn't spot the problem.

Comment: BTW, instead of typing `Transpose[position][[1]]` you can get the same result with `position[[All, 1]]`.

Comment: As your problem is currently stated, `n = Length[position]` will always work. So why bother with `n = Length[Transpose[position][[1]]]`?

Comment: @m_goldberg thank you for that, I must have been a bit sleepy when I typed that code.

Comment: Maybe it is worth pregenerating all the solutions of your ODE and use those in your `Manipulate` function. Take a look also at Mr.Wizard's solution to speed up rendering of `ListPolarPlot`.

Comment: @VLC, ok thanks for the advice. By the way, I'm accepting Mr. Wizard's answer as it really is much faster (although I didn't mention the need for efficiency at the start); thank you for your answer too, though!

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  In case you are using the first method I changed it to use a vectorized polar conversion for maximum speed.  It's unlikely to make a difference given the overhead of rendering graphics but I might as well use the faster method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For your particular problem, and *especially* since performance is important I once again<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11533/121)[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1780/121)[(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5192/121)[(4)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21129/121)</sup> recommend using `Graphics` primitives:

```
toPolar = {#2 Cos[#], #2 Sin[#]}\[Transpose] & @@ (#\[Transpose]) &;
colors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale @ Range @ Length @ position;

Graphics[
 {PointSize[Large], Point[toPolar @ position, VertexColors -> colors]},
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
 Axes -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

If you prefer to use `ListPolarPlot` for some reason (e.g. specialized Options not accepted by `Graphics`) you can still get the faster rendering of having all points in a single `Point` expression by using this:

```
colors = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale @ Range @ Length @ position;

ListPolarPlot[position, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large]] /. 
  Point[x : {__Integer}] :> Point[x, VertexColors -> colors]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: just wondering - does writing functions as such `Rescale @ Range @ Length @ position` versus writing it as such `Rescale[Range[Length[position]]]` lead to any increase in performance, or is it just good coding practice to prevent one from being confused in a thicket of brackets? I'm asking this because I noticed that you almost exclusively use `@`, `/@`, `@@` in your answers.

Comment: @Vincent It is purely notational.  *Mathematica* interprets them the same way.  If you put the code in `HoldForm[FullForm[ (*code*) ]]` and execute you will see how the expression is internally represented.  I personally dislike nested brackets and find them hard to read, so yes, I use `function @ argument`, `argument // function` and `arg1 ~function~ arg2` quite heavily, though *not* so heavily that I have to introduce additional `( )` for grouping (most of the time).

Comment: @Vincent The other notations `/@` and `@@` are a bit different; these are short for `Map` and `Apply` and I use them primarily because they are shorter.

Comment: Thank you! I'd just like to say that your use of notations like `@` made your code very difficult to read when I was a new user, but once I began to understand the beauty of it then it really helped me to understand how to code better!

Comment: @Vincent Sorry for the steep learning curve, but I'm glad that in the end you find value in it.  It will be very helpful to study the [operator precedence table](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) and memorize the order as best you can.

Answer (score 10):

You can solve your problem in this way:

```
ListPolarPlot[List /@ position, 
  PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[Large], 
  Blend[{{1, Orange}, {Length[position]/2, Red},
  {Length[position], Purple}}, #1]} & /@ Range[Length[position]])]
```

The first values from the list are colored in orange, the last in purple and those in between are red. You can choose your preferred colors just by replacing those listed above.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @VLC! Is there any way to optimize the way your code works? As the pendulums move over time, the plot has to be recalculated every time I change the value of time `t` in my `Manipulate` function, and it seems a bit slow for now.

Comment: One disadvantage to this method relative to using `Graphics` directly is that it generates a `Point` expression for every point rather than the optimized form of one `Point` for all and `VertexColors` to style them.  This significantly reduces rendering performance.

Comment: @VLC Ok. The motion of the pendulums are generated by the solution to a numerically-solved differential equation, am trying to figure out how to post my code without using up too much space.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I fully agree with your comment and I support solutions based on `Graphics` primitives. Since the question was based on a `ListPolarPlot` I gave a solution that holds for this function.

Comment: Understood.  I think the second method in my second answer addresses this well.

Answer (score 5):

While it's not the cleanest method you can use `Tooltip` or `Annotation` to pass arbitrary data through a plot function, then reprocess it on the other side.

A point passed as `Annotation[{x, y}, data]` will appear in the output `Graphics` as:

```
Annotation[{Opacity[0.], Point[n]}, data]
```

where `n` is an integer coordinate of `GraphicsComplex`.  These objects appear after the regular `Point` objects and would therefore be rendered on top of them if not for `Opacity[0.]`.

We can therefore do something like this:

```
ListPolarPlot[
  MapIndexed[Annotation[#, ColorData["Rainbow"] @@ (#2/20)] &, position],
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
  PlotStyle -> None
] /. Annotation[{__, p_Point}, s_] :> {s, PointSize[Large], p}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

While not necessary in the case I used `PlotStyle -> None` to hide the original points.

Answer (score 3):

If you have version 8 of *Mathematica* or above, you can style the perturbed points like this:

```
styleddata = 
 Style[{##}, ColorData["Rainbow"][1000*(#2 - 1)]] & @@@ position
```

Or alternatively, style the original, non-perturbed points like this:

```
origposition = {{-1.25084, 1}, {-1.42995, 1}, {-1.7497, 1}, {-1.83175,
    1}, {-1.733, 1}, {-1.86803, 1}, {-1.79935, 1}, {-1.87909, 
   1}, {-1.78354, 1}, {-1.81614, 1}, {-1.58559, 1}, {-1.71751, 
   1}, {-1.72079, 1}, {-1.60622, 1}, {-1.72122, 1}, {-1.46695, 
   1}, {-1.62577, 1}, {-1.75079, 1}, {-0.89456, 1}, {-0.950143, 
   1}, {-1.5654, 1}}

styledata2=MapThread[
 Style[#1, ColorData["Rainbow"][#2]] &, {origposition, Range[n]/n}]
```

You can then do this:

```
ListPolarPlot[styleddata (* or styleddata2 *), 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},  Joined -> False, 
 BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[8]]
```

[image]

Performance is not lagged at all even with 200 points:

```
Manipulate[
 With[{data = {#, 1 - t} & /@ Range[-1.7, -0.7, 0.005]}, 
  With[{restyle = 
     MapThread[
      Style[#1, ColorData["Rainbow"][#2]] &, {data, 
       Range[Length@data]/Length@data}]}, 
   ListPolarPlot[restyle, BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[5], 
    PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 1}, {-1.2, 0}}] ]], {t, 0.01, 0.5, 0.001}]
```

Comment: This doesn't work in version 7.  In later versions does this produce the slow one-`Point`-per-point output or the fast `VertexColors` output?

Comment: Sorry @Mr.Wizard - I'll note that this is a version 8+ solution. The `FullForm` seems to involve `Points` but it feels pretty fast on my four-year-old machine.

Comment: How well does it do in a `Manipulate` with hundreds of points?  On my system the multi-`Point` form has significant lag, whereas `VertexColors` is very quick.

Comment: @Verbeia thank you for your answer, I'll have to look through this and run it when I get back to my computer with Mathematica installed.

Comment: @Verbeia thank you! What's very interesting for me is that the output for styledata2 appears coloured. Is it the MapThread function that is doing this?

Comment: @VincentTjeng yes, either method wraps the `Style` around each number. When you display the data on its own, it's styled.