# ArrayPlot with variable width bars

Tags: plotting

I've been using a DateList plot to visualise property information but I don't think it's the best way display my data. My data is formatted as {time (hours), property} where property is an integer between 1 and 20

```
data = {{0, 0}, {0.2187, 3}, {0.25, 1}, {0.3715, 15}, {0.868, 
1}, {1.261, 15}, {1.4595, 1}, {1.583, 15}, {2.088, 1}, {2.35, 
0}, {2.57, 1}, {3., 0}, {4., 1}, {5.226, 0}, {8.537, 1}, {10, 
0}, {11.1359, 1}, {13, 0}, {14, 1}, {14.11, 16}}

DateListPlot[data]
```

I would like to use something like an ArrayPlot but instead of having constant width the width of the bars would be dependent on the time in my data. The colour of the bar would be dependent on the property value. Similar to this plot but instead of having % it would have date;

[image]

My data is generally thousands of rows. I use manipulate to present a subset (window) of a couple of months of data which I can move through. I bring this up because any solution will have to be able to handle larger data sets than I have supplied in this question.

Comment: `ArrayPlot[]` doesn't have "bars" ... Could you draw a picture showing what you want?

Comment: is [this Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58604/125) relevant/useful?

Comment: I've added a picture. It's more like a stacked bar chart on its side with the colour being defined by the property value.

Comment: @kguler - nice. I may be able to modify that one to get what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The terse [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) primitives approach:

```
Graphics[{
  EdgeForm[{Black, Thick}],
  {ColorData[39][#2], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {#, 1}]} & @@@ Reverse[data]
  },
 Axes -> {True, False}
]
```

[image]

You can add whatever [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) specification or function you wish to label the data line appropriately.

Comment: I sat there for 15 seconds wondering why on Earth you reversed the data :)

Comment: 0.05 seconds for my 3,311 row datatset. Using the graphics primitives makes a huge speed difference, even if they don't have all the bells a whistles. I'll give this one the answer because I did bring up performance in my original question.

Comment: @Cam Thanks for the Accept.  `Graphics` is my preferred method for custom plotting, e.g.:  [(1780)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1780/121),
[(5192)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5192/121),
[(11533)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11533/121),
[(21129)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21129/121),
[(21134)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21134/121),
[(22953)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/22953/121).  The performance is usually better and behavior rarely changes, unlike various plotting functions.

Comment: @Cam (continued from above) It is quite annoying to get a plot just right, then have its appearance change when *Mathematica* is updated.  By the way, if you have any trouble adding a legend to this let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I'll let you know if I have trouble figuring out the legend.

Comment: One more thing. If the size of the data increases you need to scale the height of the rectangle to stop it looking too thin.

Answer (score 3):

```
Row[{Column[{
  Plot[Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0][x], {x, 0, Max[data[[All, 1]]]}, 
       PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/4, ImageSize -> 600, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}, 
       ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotStyle -> Thick], 
  BarChart[Thread[Differences@data[[All, 1]] -> data[[2 ;;, 2]]], ImageSize -> 600, 
     ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Left, AspectRatio -> 1/10,
     ChartElementFunction -> Function[{region, values, metadata}, 
                                      {ColorData[{"Rainbow", {0, 16}}][metadata[[1]]], 
                                      EdgeForm[Thick], Rectangle @@ (Transpose@region)}]]}], 
  BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 16}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very nice. ChartElementFunction seems to be the bit I was missing. The performance I get on my machine is 31 seconds for a dataset with 3,311 elements which is probably acceptable. Is it worth looking into using graphics primitives like Rectangle if I want faster speeds?

Comment: @Cam Yes, that will be much faster

Comment: I was planning on adding a legend but the colours would need to be discrete because the property value is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Completely rewritten following the clarification. If those are timestamps, then the height of the bars should be the `Differences` of the first column. Then style these heights according to the value of the second element of the pair, like this.

```
transformeddata = 
 With[{max = Max[data[[All, 2]]]}, 
  MapThread[
   Style[#1, Blend[{Red, Blue}, N@#2]] &, {Join[{1}, 
     Differences[data[[All, 1]]]], data[[All, 2]]/max}] ]
```

[image]

You can then use a normal bar chart:

```
BarChart[transformeddata, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Left]
```

[image]

Comment: I've updated by question to provide more clarity. Basically the property (1->20) would be better represented as a colour instead of the height of the bar.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the methods suggested in previosly posted answers and in [this related Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58604/125), there is also ...

`Graphics` with thick `Line`s (instead of `Rectangle`s):

```
colorRules = Thread[# -> Charting`CommonDump`brightrogerStyles[Length@#]] &@
                   DeleteDuplicates[data[[All, 2]]];
colors = labels /. colorRules;
ldata = Partition[Thread[{dates, 1}], 2, 1];
Graphics[{Thickness[.1], CapForm[None], Transpose[{colors, Line /@ ldata}]}]
```

[image]

```
colorRules = Thread[# -> ColorData[5, "ColorList"][[;; Length@#]]] &@
               DeleteDuplicates[data[[All, 2]]];
colors = data[[All,2]] /. colorRules;
Graphics[{Thickness[.1], CapForm["Butt"], Transpose[{colors, Line /@ ldata}]}]
```

[image]

`MatrixPlot`

```
max = Max[data[[All, 1]]];
mindif = Min[Differences[dates]];
widths = Round[Differences[dates]/mindif];
labels = data[[All, 2]];
mpdata = {Flatten@(ConstantArray[#2, {#}] & @@@ Transpose[{widths, labels}])};
options = {Frame -> False, AspectRatio -> 1/15, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0};
MatrixPlot[mpdata, options, ColorFunction -> Hue]
```

[image]

```
Column[Labeled[MatrixPlot[mpdata, options, ColorFunction -> #], 
    Style[#, "Panel", 16], Right] & /@ {"Rainbow", "TemperatureMap", 
   "SolarColors", "DeepSeaColors", "BlueGreenYellow"}, Spacings -> 1]
```

[image]

Comment: There's a bit of an issue with this approach for large datasets. My 3,311 row dataset fails due to lack of memory.

Comment: @Cam,  actually it is a big issue. I made some changes to make the size of the transformed data somewhat smaller... but I wouldn't use it for large data sets.