# How can I make an linear breakdown chart similar to those seen on iCloud?

Tags: graphics, plotting

How can I make a interval breakdown chart like this:

[image]

Update: I checked `BarChart` and `Gauge` they do not have this capacity.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [`BarChart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart.html) documentation? (See under Scope > Data and Layouts.)

Comment: Also look at documentation on `Multivalue Gauges`.

Comment: `http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BulletGauge.html`

Comment: What about `BarChart[RandomReal[1, {4}], ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Left]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(64265)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64265/121)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perhaps easier (or almost so) to build this kind of chart from graphics primitives as to build it with `BarChart`. Here is a function that works that way.

```
breakdownChart[
    vals_List, lbls_List, 
    wd_Integer /; wd >= 100, 
    ht_Integer /; ht >= 20] /; Length@vals == Length@lbls :=
  With[{totl = Total @ values},
    With[{barSize = Round[wd values/totl]},
      Module[{offset = 0, next, bar},
        Framed[
          Graphics[{
            Table[
              bar = {
                Hue[offset/wd], 
                Tooltip[
                  Rectangle[{offset, 0}, {next = offset + barSize[[i]], ht}], 
                  Column[{Style[labels[[i]], "SB", 14], values[[i]]}],
                  TooltipStyle -> Background -> GrayLevel[.92]],
                Black, 
                Line[{{next, 0}, {offset, 0}, {offset, ht}, {next, ht}}]};
              offset = next;
              bar,
              {i, Length@values}],
            Line[{{offset, 0}, {offset, ht}}]},
            PlotRange -> {{0, wd}, {0, ht}},
            ImageSize -> {wd, ht}],
          RoundingRadius -> 5]]]]
```

To see how it looks, some test data is needed.

```
SeedRandom[3]; values = RandomInteger[100, 8]
```

> ```
> {61, 32, 80, 9, 58, 35, 96, 17}
> ```

```
SeedRandom[1111]; labels = RandomSample[DictionaryLookup[__ ~~ "ing"], Length @ values]
```

> ```
> {"bluffing", "fawning", "threading", "upbraiding", 
>  "overgeneralizing", "validating", "biding", "owing"}
> ```

Here is a chart with dimensions 400 by 40 pixels made with the test data.

```
breakdownChart[values, labels, 400, 40]
```

[image: breakdownChart]

#### Note

To those who wonder why I used

```
Black, Line[{{next, 0}, {offset, 0}, {offset, ht}, {next, ht}}]
```

rather than applying

```
EdgeForm[Black]
```

to the rectangles (my first thought), it is because, on OS X, `EdgeForm` gave a ugly looking result with doubled vertical black lines between the bar segments.

#### Update

I am edited this post, revising the function `breakdownChart` to use vertical dividers rather than full outlines around the segment rectangles. The new code is a little simpler and produces a better looking chart.

```
breakdownChart[
    vals_List, lbls_List,
    wd_Integer /; wd >= 100,
    ht_Integer /; ht >= 20] /; Length@vals == Length@lbls :=
  With[{totl = Total @ values},
    With[{barSize = Round[wd values/totl]},
      Module[{offset = 0, divider, next, bar},
        divider = {Black, AbsoluteThickness[1.5], Line[{{#, 0}, {#, ht}}]} &;
        Framed[
          Graphics[{
            Table[
              bar = {
                Hue[offset/wd],
                Tooltip[
                  Rectangle[{offset, 0}, {next = offset + barSize[[i]], ht}],
                  Column[{Style[labels[[i]], "SB", 14], values[[i]]}],
                  TooltipStyle -> Background -> GrayLevel[.92]],
                divider[offset]};
              offset = next;
              bar,
              {i, Length@values}],
            divider[offset]},
            PlotRange -> {{0, wd}, {0, ht}},
            PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[1/wd], Automatic},
            ImageSize -> {wd, ht}],
          RoundingRadius -> 5]]]]

breakdownChart[values, labels, 400, 40]
```

[image: breakdownChart]

Comment: Any chance you can add non-tooltip labels to callout the big sections?

Comment: Not sure I buy the "easier" argument but +1 nonetheless.  Does the Tooltip shadow come automatically on OS X?  The default tooltip style is amazingly awful in the PC version.

Comment: @bobthechemist. Whether or not it's easier is a matter of opinion. I did say "or almost so" :) The look of the tooltip including the drop shadow is OS X standard, except for the background color which was changed with a tooltip option.

Comment: @M.R. Adding labels to the larger segments is bit tricky or at least fussy. I know of no simple way to get the bounding box of displayed text in _Mathematica_. That is this the main reason that I did put that feature in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way to to it with `BarChart`.  I didn't spend too much time on formatting the `Tooltip`.

```
names = {"apps", "pics", "vids", "free"};
vals = {10, 25, 50, 15};
BarChart[
 Table[Tooltip[vals[[i]], Column[{
     Style[names[[i]], 16, Bold],
     Style[ToString[vals[[i]]] <> " GB", 16, GrayLevel[0.5]]}],
   TooltipStyle -> {CellFrameColor -> GrayLevel[0.9], 
     Background -> GrayLevel[0.9]}], {i, 1, 4}],
 ChartLayout -> "Stacked", BarOrigin -> Left, Axes -> False, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/8]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering first! The other solution was just a bit more general though.

Answer (score 3):

Bottom-up approach using `Accumulate`:

```
{10, 25, 50, 15} // Prepend[0] // Accumulate // Partition[#, 2, 1] & // 
  Map[{ColorData["HTML", RandomInteger[{1, 10}]], 
      Rectangle[{First[#], 0}, {Last[#], 1}]}~
     Join~ {Black, Text[Last[#], {Last[#], -1/4}]} &] // 
 Graphics[#, AspectRatio -> 1/5] &
```

[image]

`RandomInteger` color selection is not recommended, only used for brevity.